# CakePHP 3.7 Shell commands inside a plugin couldn't execute

Tags: cakephp-3.7

```
namespace Admin\Shell;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
class AdminAlertShell extends Shell{
  ...
  ...
}
```

Here 'Admin' is  plugin, So I created this file inside the plugins folder structure.
File path : /plugins/Admin/src/Shell/AdminAlertShell.php

Tried to run this in CLI

```
bin/cake admin_alert
```

But an exception throws

Exception: Unknown command `cake admin_alert`. Run `cake --help` to get the list of valid commands. in [localpath/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php, line 346]

It was working. But I don't know what happened to this. I had upgraded cakephp 3.5 to 3.7. But, I am not sure this caused the issue.

Comment: CakePHP are depreciating use of shells from 3.6 onward. In their documentation https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html, they mention the following
"New in version 3.6.0: Commands were added to replace Shells long term. Shells & Tasks have several shortcomings that are hard to correct without breaking compatibility."

Comment: @HasnatSafder Thanks for the quick reply.
Yes, It's depreciating. But its work fine outside the plugin. Only when I put it inside the plugin folder the issue occurs. When I create a Command folder inside the plugin, the exception "command not found" throws.

Comment: While working with CakePHP 3.6 onwards i have never read about using commands outside the main src/commands directory.

Comment: Maybe your files/classes cannot be found/accessed, for example because of permission problems or spelling mistakes, or maybe your plugin isn't loaded (check your `Application` class' bootstrap).

Comment: @ndm It was working. So no chance for spelling mistake or plugin not loading issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just tracked down the source of the issue in my project.

Inside my plugin there was a file: src/Plugin.php

Inside this class there was the following lines of code:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function console(CommandCollection $commands): CommandCollection
{
    // Add console commands here.
    return $commands;
}
```

This was probably generated via bake.

I saw that the parent was not called. In the path is added in the parent.

Change this method to look like this:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function console(CommandCollection $commands): CommandCollection
{
    // Add console commands here.
    $commands = parent::console($commands);
    return $commands;
}
```

Now the parent is called and the path is added to the command collection.

As a side note I also see the middleware is not calling its parent.

Think it would be a good idea to fix that one aswell.

As an alternative you can just clear out the class and all defaults should be used.

Hope this saves someone the hours it cost me to figure this one out.

Comment: I just checked the latest bake template and see the console method is removed but the middleware method still exists. I checked the middleware source and see it only returns the middleware object so there is no need to call the parent